# How do I write a script for that finds the sum of a range in Google Sheets, then divides that by the number of months that have elapsed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a ledger where I record how much money I earn each month. Since I bill bi-monthly, I record two figures for each month. I'd like to find my average monthly income so that I can automatically send that figure to my budget sheet.

The formula is relatively simple: `=(SUM(J3:J26))/((month(TODAY()-1)))` (J3:J26 is my range.) But the fact that I'm recording two figures for each month means that my average will be inaccurate after I write my second monthly figure. This is why I've determined I need to write this as a script with a timed trigger for the 1st of the month. I tried this the following way:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    s.getRange("K30").setFormula("=(SUM(J3:J26))/(month(TODAY()-1))");
 }
```

but it just inserts the formula into the sheet, rather than executing the formula only once a month. Obviously, I'm very new to sheets and scripts, so I'd appreciate any insight here. How do I get this formula to run only once a month? Or is there some other alternative?

Comment: Welcome. If you didn't this yet please https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. There you will learn that learning about JavaScript and muldimensional arrays will be worthy. Then you might [edit] your question to make it more specific and to include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The question you asked in the headline seems to have nothing to do with the question you asked later. Compare "How do I write a script for that finds the sum of a range in Google Sheets, then divides that by the number of months that have elapsed?"  and "How do I get this formula to run only once a month?". Please limit to one question per post and add more focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Average monthly income on the first day of every month**

```
function myFunction() {
  var dt=new Date();
  //Let it run on first day of ever month
  if(dt.getDate()==1) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID');
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
    sh.getRange("K30").setFormula("=(SUM(J3:J26))/(month(TODAY()-1))");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    sh.getRange("K30").setValue(sh.getRange("K30").getDisplayValue());
  }
}

//Run this to create trigger for above function the trigger runs every day sometime between 2 and 3 am.
function createTrigger() {
  var pt=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<pt.length;i++) {
    if(pt[i].getHandlerFunction()=='myfunction') {
      found=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myfunction').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(2).create();
  }
}
```